# how to replace /r with &#10; using string.replace

Tags: javascript, newline, linefeed

I am sending json data from a textarea and then inserting it to a database a s a clob because I am working with XML. after I read the text from the database and display it in a browser, It doesn't preserve the newlines. all the newlines are displayed as spaces.

so basically if I insert this to a database:

```
Hello
World
```

After I read the clob from the database, it will display

```
Hello World
```

I found out that If I replace newlines with the linefeed character, it preserves the newline:

```
Hello&#10;World
```

gets displayed as

```
Hello
World
```

now I am trying to replace the newlines with 
 using javascript. I have the following code:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\n','g'), '&#10;')
```

but it doesn't seem to understand the right part of the code, I mean the linefeed character.

Answer (score 0):

Following the doc about the [replace() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
str.replace(/\n/g, '&#10;')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `str.replace()` returns the new string, so you have to assign it to a new value

You can do something like this

```js
var p = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

// space between splash
var regex = / /gi; 
    
//Assign p the new value
p = p.replace(regex, '\n');

console.log(p);
```